# Set a global variable in an arrow function node

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to get the message before the current message as a variable.
Here is my code:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 }).then(messages => {
          prevMsg = messages.last()
      }).catch(err => {
          console.error(err)
      }) 
        console.log("prevMsg is " + prevMsg)
```

But I get a `ReferenceError: prevMsg is not defined` at the line where my `console.log` is.
My question is how can I set the variable in that arrow function so that the variable is accessible elsewhere or if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call you have there is asynchronous that is why it is undefined...

```
const prevMsg;

message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 })
  .then(messages => {
      prevMsg = messages.last()
  }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
  });

// the call above runs asynchronously that is why loggin here comes out undefined
// it has not been assigned yet...
console.log(prevMsg);
```

You need to implement a way to wait for the call to finish, you cant use a global await but you can wrap this in a function that is asynchronous also...

```
async function myfunction() {

  const prevMsg = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 })
    .then(messages => messages.last())
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    });

  // this should work
  console.log(prevMsg);

}
```